# my vps not able to boot

Tags: 14.04, boot-repair

I have a VPS with cPANEL installed. It was working well until last week. Since last week it stopped working it seems that the system is not able to load the boot drive. I used boot-repair-disk but due to my low experience in linux not able to manage any proper solution. Using boot-repai-disk I have managed to get the link with details of the problem with the system . http://paste.ubuntu.com/16453115/.

please check & help me solve the problem
thanks
Shakti